# What does "in some cases" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have heard this sentence a couple of times but have not understood its meaning properly. so what does it mean?

> "in some cases, it is correct"

what does "in some cases" mean in this sentence?

also, what does the sentence below mean in simple words?

> "he is tall for his age"

Answer (score 2):

One of the definitions of "case" is a "set of circumstances" or an "instance".  So "in some cases it is correct" is saying that this is sometimes correct, but implying that it is not always correct.

As far as "he is tall for his age", this implies that, when compared to some  group of similarly aged people, he is taller than the average height of that group.